# How to publish provider hosted app in SharePoint store?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, provider-hosted-app, app

I am trying to publish provider hosted app. But i am unable to find how to publish it. Previously i did it but at that time, seller dashboard was completely different. But when i checked it now, it totally different. 
Can anybody help?

I referred lots of Microsoft blogs but i am unable to follow it as i can't find link on that page.

I am using these (https://partner.microsoft.com/en-us/pcv/dashboard/overview) page to publish my app.

Please help me.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Hope these articles are helpful to you:

[Publish SharePoint Add-ins by using Visual Studio](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/publish-sharepoint-add-ins-by-using-visual-studio)

[Deploying a provider hosted SharePoint APP to AZURE and SharePoint Online](https://www.imaginet.com/2015/deploying-a-provider-hosted-sharepoint-app-to-azure-and-sharepoint-online/)